# JMeter - trouble configuring payload for jmeter-server test connecting over SSH

Tags: configuration, jms, jmeter

I'm tearing my hair out over a JMeter config issue. I'm running JMeter on a dedicated injection server, using the gui on my local box to control the tests [EDIT: The connection is SSH. The client is Windows 7 and the server is Linux). I've run the tests from my local box and I confirmed that they're working correctly from there. I put the payload (text files containing one JSON object each) on to the injection server and changed the Publisher configuration in the message source section so the path pointed to the files on there and...nothing.

This is the only output I get:

```
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.StandardSampleSender: Using StandardSampleSender for this test run 
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.StandardSampleSender: Using StandardSampleSender for this test run 
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to <IP_ADDRESS_OBSCURED> basedir='.' 
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
2012/09/24 14:26:50 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to <IP_ADDRESS_OBSCURED>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried Apache's highly comprehensive documentation, but surprisingly there's nothing at all about this. How should I be configuring the path to the payload on the server?

Comment: I solved it now - thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I solved this one today and was on my way home to post the answer. The important thing to note is that the tests weren't running at all. The server reported stop-start but the tests weren't running. This is why:

I was using a JMS Producer sampler and connecting over SSH. This was part of the problem. In order to connect to a remote SSH server, it's necessary first to create an SSH tunnel, then start the JMeter server and client with special parameters. The process is described in this helpful and concise blog post:

http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/02/16/how-to-run-jmeter-over-ssh-tunnel/

The second mistake I was making was that I was running the server on a Linux box (CentOS) and the client on a Windows 7 desktop. It's not recommended to do this, but I didn't realise that it'd stop the test from running. I dropped a Linux VM on my windows box, ran the tests from there and everything worked perfectly.